# This attempt to set a cookie via a Set-Cookie was blocked because it used the "__secure" or __HOST

Tags: security, cookies, browser

I have simple Go application which sets a cookie. I like it to be secure cookie and reading the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) I set the cookie to be "__Host".

It looks like this in the client:

```
__Host-refresh_token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE2OTkwMDQ1MTAsImlhdCI6MTY5OTAwMzA3MCwic3ViIjoiMSJ9.8VDKxv2skkIK5cjiFgEWutaVJcepzgYadWSFjUqEPqc; Path=/; Domain=localhost; Expires=Fri, 03 Nov 2023 09:41:50 GMT; Max-Age=1440; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=Strict
```

but now I'm getting warning like this in the browser:

[image]

and I can't see the cookie was created  in the browser. If I remove the "__" from Host then everything working fine.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error message pop-up is over some of the information needed to diagnose other issues, but one issue is that you are serving the response over HTTP, which the browser will not consider a secure transport when using this specific type of cookie. For many features that need a secure transport, most browsers have been implemented to consider the `http` scheme to be "secure" when used on `localhost`, just not this feature.

This form of cookie has a few rules:

- It must include a Secure attribute.
- It must be set from a URI that the browser considers secure (i.e. HTTPS or other secured transports).
- It cannot include the Domain attribute.
- It must include a Path attribute of /

So, you want the Set-Cookie to look like `Set-Cookie: __Host-key=value; Secure; Path=/` and you need to serve it over HTTPS.